# PHP Fatal Error. Does empty() try to alter the results passed into it?

Tags: php

Ran into a strange problem in PHP today and I'm wondering if someone can explain it.  While comparing two arrays I initially tried something like this:

```
echo empty(array_diff( array('foo','bar') , array('bar','foo') ))
```

This results in the following error:

> Fatal Error: Can't use function return value in write context

Rewriting this as...

```
$dif = array_diff( array('foo','bar') , array('bar','foo') );
echo empty($dif);
```

...works perfectly.  Empty should just be evaluating the value passed in to it, not writing to it, so what's going wrong here?  Tested in both PHP 5.2.10 and PHP 5.3.2.

---

I've resolved the issue by using `!count()` instead of `empty()`, but I'm curious why it doesn't work in the first place.  Is `empty()` trying to alter the result from `array_diff`?

Comment: Googling for 'php empty' would have found you the answer much faster!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the [manual on empty():](http://www.php.net/empty)

> **Note:** empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.

`empty()`, like e.g. `echo()` and `die()`, is a language construct, and therefore has different rules than a normal function (in which your example would work fine).

Comment: For convenience, you can create a function: `function isEmpty($var) { return empty($var); }`